# Ubuntu SSH alias for remote subfolder

Tags: ssh, alias, bashrc

I'm trying to make it ease for me by creating **alias for ssh connection** to my server. So I created alias in the

```
~/.bashrc
```

as follows:

```
alias aliasname='ssh login@ip -p 59184'
```

But I want to make several diffent aliases for my subfolders on the server. I tried to to something like

```
alias aliasname='ssh login@ip:/path/to/subfolder -p 59184'
alias aliasname='ssh login@ip/path/to/subfolder -p 59184'
alias aliasname='ssh login@ip::/path/to/subfolder -p 59184'
```

but always get error like **Name or service not known**, so clearly I do it wrong. Can someone help me here?

P.S. I should mention that regular alias to the server root works fine.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. What is `ssh login@ip:/path/to/subfolder` supposed to do? When you login through `ssh`, you always "land" in the home directory. Accordingly, telling `ssh` a destination directory is not meaningful, and thus it does not understand it.

Comment: it supposed to enter that specified directory.

Comment: Ok. This is not intended by default, so you have to arrange for it by yourself, see siloko's answer (which you may not only accept but also upvote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of thing which can and should be achieved by an ssh config file in your ~/.ssh directory. See the man pages here:

https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

EDIT: actually you can't change remote dirs in the config file, see this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387872/ssh-config-file-alias-to-get-to-a-directory-on-server

Which basically has this in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host dev
  Hostname server.com
  User joe
```

and this in ~/.bash_profile

```
alias domain1 = "ssh dev -t 'cd domains/domain1; bash'"
```